# Only getting first row from table in jdbc

Tags: java, jdbc

I only get the first row from table, from a JDBC call.

Below is my code

```
import java.util.*;
import java.sql.*;

public class TrainManagementSystem {
    
    public ArrayList <Train> viewTrain (String coachType, String source, String destination){
        
        Connection myCon = null;
        PreparedStatement myStat = null;
        ResultSet myRes = null;
        ArrayList<Train> result = new ArrayList<>();
        try{
            myCon = DB.getConnection();
            myStat = myCon.prepareStatement("select * from train where source = ? and destination = ? and ? > 0");
            myStat.setString(1, source);
            myStat.setString(2, destination);
            myStat.setString(3, coachType);
            
            myRes = myStat.executeQuery();
            
            while(myRes.next()){
                int train_number = myRes.getInt("train_number");
                String train_name = myRes.getString("train_name");
                String source1 = myRes.getString("source");
                String destination1 = myRes.getString("destination");
                int ac1 = myRes.getInt("ac1");
                int ac2 = myRes.getInt("ac2");
                int ac3 = myRes.getInt("ac3");
                int sleeper = myRes.getInt("sleeper");
                int seater = myRes.getInt("seater");
                System.out.println(myRes.getString("train_name"));
                Train train = new Train(train_number, train_name, source1, destination1, ac1, ac2, ac3, sleeper, seater);
                result.add(train);
                return result;
            }
        }catch(Exception e){
            System.out.println(e);
        }
        return result;
    }

}
```

I only get the first row in result set in JDBC. The query is not retrieving the second row.
I have attached my entries in table.
When giving input as

[image: Input table]

Why is it not going to next row? When I try removing coachtype and only search for train between Howrah and Dehradun, it gives me result Dehradun Mail whereas the result should add Doon Express as well.

[image: This is my table record]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you have a `return result;` inside your while loop.
Move it line down outside of the loop